# How to set same page transition for every navigation in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I use Pagecontainer widget for navigation. There is an option `allowSamePageTransition`, when set to true it does exactly what its name says. It can be used like so:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', '#myPage', {allowSamePageTransition: true});
```

I would like not to specify this option every time, rather set this option to `true` for all navigations by default. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `changePage` default on `mobileinit`. Place the code below after jquery.js and before jquery mobile.js in `<head>`.

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
  $.mobile.changePage.defaults.allowSamePageTransition = true;
});
```